# Sending HTTP Post request crashes Android program

Tags: android, http, post

I feel like providing you with my code is my best bet.

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Button submitbtn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            submitbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    PostDataAsyncTask runner = new PostDataAsyncTask();
                    runner.execute();
                }
            });
        }
```

**OTHER METHODS AND CLASSES INSIDE MAIN ACTIVITY**

**PostDataAsyncTask** (Unused overriden methods omitted)

```
    public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            postData();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**PostData() method**

```
    private void postData(){
        try{
            String postReceiverUrl = "staffappfeedback.comule.com/insert-dp.php";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Mike"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("summary", "My suggestion"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "This is what I think you should do"));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {

                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have enabled internet access in the Mainifest File.

A lot of the Classes/Objects have strikethroughs on them (i.e.- is deprecated).

Why might this be the case?

Is this the reason my program is crashing?

My android device has issues debugging so I can't locate the problem easily, hence the post on Stack Overflow, but don't get me wrong, I have spent ages trying to find the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use AppCompat activity instead of ActionBarActivity. It's not the solution. Just a suggestion. Since google has finally decided to go with AppCompatActivity and deprecating ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Does this work with all versions of android?

Comment: Please post the crash log

Comment: postReceiverUrl doesn't start with `"http://"`

Comment: Yeah, sure. It uses AppCompat library, which is the one Google specifically made for supporting all versions of android

Comment: I have tried it with `"http://`, no difference unfortunately. My logcat is empty, this happens regularly, I think it is possibly my USB connection, but I suppose this is a different issue

Comment: Could you run in an emulator and then post the crashlog?

Comment: What's your PHP script ? If i call from webbrowser it return Error: INSERT INTO comments VALUES (NULL, , , )
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , )' at line 1

Comment: @eurosecom The PHP script accesses the values "name", "summary" and "description". When android runs the PHP script it pushes the values that can be accessed through the `_POST` method. It is pointless running the PHP script on its own. But out of curiosity, can faulty PHP code cause a crash in the android program?

Comment: @TmKVU The emulator runs far too slow on my i7 laptop. Any idea why?

Comment: @GregoryPeck maybe you did not supply enough ram for the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed postData() to

```
private void postData(){
    try{
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://staffappfeedback.comule.com/insert-dp.php";

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 2000);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpParameters.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);
        httpPost.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 5000);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Mike"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("summary", "My suggestion"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "This is what I think you should do"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(formEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();

        Log.e("result", result);


        //HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


        //if (resEntity != null) {

            //String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

        //}

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and log response from server is

```
06-21 14:34:59.325: E/result(3794): Error: INSERT INTO comments VALUES     (NULL, android, android test, this is an android test)<br>You have an error in     your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test, this is an android test)' at line 1
```

Problem is in addition to change line String postReceiverUrl = "http://staffappfeedback.comule.com/insert-dp.php"; with your PHP script.